# Saving html2canvas image to a specific folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, html2canvas

I am trying to add a generated image to a RazorPDF in my MVC application. I was thinking I could generate the image with html2canvas (works) then save the image to a temp folder and add the image to the PDF when the PDF is generated.

The issue is I'm not sure how to save the generated image to a temp folder. I'm just lost as to what the next step is. After Googling, it doesn't look like there is a way to save with JQuery.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newImg = $("#img-out");

     //emptys the dom
     newImg.empty();

      //creates the image from the div
      html2canvas($('#printable'), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
             newImg.append(canvas);
             newImg.toDataUrl("image/png");
          }
     });
});
```

**Razor**

```
<div id="printable" style="float:left">
    <div>Image Stuff</div>
</div>  
<div id="img-out"></div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this topic: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907269/how-to-save-html2canvas-image-into-system-folder-in-jquery]?

Comment: ah good call. looks like a duplicate, my mistake.